# error while checking adjacent cells in 2d array

Tags: c++, implementation, similarity

the code is for chess board each chessmen `B` for black and `W` for white 
, where `W` and `B`  should not share the same edge.

Example:

```
WBWB
BWBW
WBWB
BWBW
```

My code is:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    char chess[4][4];
    for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
        for (int j = 0;j<m;j++)
            cin >> chess[i][j];

    for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
        for (int j = 0;j<m;j++)
        {
            if (chess[i][j] == '.')
            {
                if (chess[i - 1][j] == 'W' || chess[i + 1][j] == 'W' || chess[i][j + 1] == 'W' || chess[i][j - 1] == 'W')
                    chess[i][j] = 'B';
                else
                    chess[i][j] = 'W';
            }
        }
    for (int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0;j<m;j++)
            cout << chess[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I run this code the output is:

```
WBWB
BWBW
BBWB
WBBW
```

I debugged it and `chess[2][-1]` equals to `W` , it's out of scope so it's supposed to be garbage.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a negative array index's.  When `i` or `j` is zero then

```
chess[i - 1][j]
// and
chess[i][j - 1]
```

becomes

```
chess[-1][j]
// and
chess[i][-1]
```

And using an negative array index is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and anything can happen.  You need to add bounds checking to make sure that you are not using an index less than zero or more than 3.  YOu also need to check `chess[i + 1][j]` and `chess[i][j + 1]` as when `i` or `j` equals 3 you go out of bounds again.

Comment: I get the idea of the undefined behavior. but is there an easier way for the bounds checking ?

Using If statements will make the code too long